How Can I Add Field All Collections With Firestore
I need to add a field to a collection of approximately 2 million. Is there an easy way to do this? If I am going to do this with batch write, how should I query the fields that do not exist?

What do you mean by "query the fields that do not exist"?

Do I need to find non-existent fields to query these fields using Batch Write?

Let me explain it this way: batch write can perform 500 operations. If I want to add this field manually, I think I need to constantly query fields that do not exist, or I do not know if there is a simpler way?


I think I need to constantly query fields that do not exist.

There is no way you can query Firestore for something that doesn't exist. A field needs to exist in order for a Firestore index to be aware of it.
So you will have to query for an existing field so that a Firestore query returns the expected results. In your particular case, you have to read all documents in the collection and right after that perform the desired update.
Please also note that such an operation cannot be performed in a single go. You have to query the collection first and then call update(Map<Object, Object?> data) on the DocumentReference object.
